# Twitter streaming API - per day limits

Tags: python-2.7, twitter

I am currently working on project to analyse the daily tweets real-time. Is there any per day limit for the api - like using the api I can have only 10000 tweet data per day or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

> Once applications establish a connection to a streaming endpoint, they are delivered a feed of Tweets, without needing to worry about polling or REST API rate limits.

https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/public